# Splitting list of strings in a column of vaex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

There is a vaex dataframe with a column such as:

```
df['col']

['aa', ' NO']
['aa', ' NO']
['aa', ' NO']
['aa', ' NO']
['aa', ' NO']
```

I want to convert this one column to two columns as follow:

```
df['col1', 'col2']

['aa'], [' NO']
['aa'], [' NO']
['aa'], [' NO']
['aa'], [' NO']
['aa'], [' NO']
```

Is there any way to do that in Vaex?

Answer (score 0):

I do like that (not very clean but ok. Maybe You can use `find` method to if you dont know where is str word start or end ):

```
    df.head(10)
>>>        col
>>> 0   ['aa', 'NO']
>>> 1   ['aa', 'NO']
>>> 2   ['aa', 'NO']
>>> 3   ['aa', 'NO']
>>> 4   ['aa', 'NO']

df['col1'] = [[x[1:5]] for x in df['col']]
df['col2'] = [[x[7:11]] for x in df['col']]

df.head(10)
>>>             col    col1    col2
>>> 0  ['aa', 'NO']  ['aa']  ['NO']
>>> 1  ['aa', 'NO']  ['aa']  ['NO']
>>> 2  ['aa', 'NO']  ['aa']  ['NO']
>>> 3  ['aa', 'NO']  ['aa']  ['NO']
>>> 4  ['aa', 'NO']  ['aa']  ['NO']
```